# web page is not loading showing 304 error in network tab . hosted app in aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i have hosted simple web page with some cdn links of j query, google maps but all the links are showing 304 and 302 responses. and page not loading with some content. some part of the page is loaded and some part of the page is not loaded.

i have hosted in AWS ec2. is there any setting i need to change.

Comment: Did you check what the browser debug console says? You will find informative message in there as well as errors.

Comment: its running in local host. but not running in the server.there are 2 errors. Expected identifier. const [p1_latitude, p1_longitude] =data[0].split('#'); in this line im getting eroor. but in my local host its working and also working in other server godaddy